# How to get all data in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I am not getting all in the csv. getting ...

Data:

```
                     0         ...                             5
0         Project Name         ...                 Other Details
1   SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...            SKV S ANANDA VILAS
2         Project Name         ...                 Other Details
3   SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...            SKV S ANANDA VILAS
4         Project Name         ...                 Other Details
5   SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...            SKV S ANANDA VILAS
6         Project Name         ...                 Other Details
7   SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...            SKV S ANANDA VILAS
8         Project Name         ...                 Other Details
9   SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...            SKV S ANANDA VILAS
10        Project Name         ...                 Other Details
11  SKV S ANANDA VILAS         ...           SKV S ANANDAM VILAS
```

**Edit**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

res = requests.get("http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTQmRGl2aXNpb249MSZVc2VySUQ9MjAyODcmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NSZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNIJkNoYXJhY3RlckQ9MjImRXh0QXBwSUQ9")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

table_data = []

for i in range(len(soup.find_all('table'))):

    table = soup.find_all('table')[i] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))

    #print (df)
    with open('D:/out_table.csv', 'a') as outcsv:   
    #configure writer to write standard csv file
        writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
        for item in df:
            for i in range(len(item)):
                print (item[0: i])
                writer.writerow(item[0: i])
```

By using above code, able to write csv file but I am getting some data ... ... ... please suggest How to write all data as same in web or in propare format.

Or Tried

```
for i in range(len(soup.find_all('table'))):

    table = soup.find_all('table')[i] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    table_data.append(df)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
for i in range(len(my_df)):
    my_df.loc[[i]].to_csv('D:/my_csv.csv',
        index=True,
        header=True,
        mode='a')
```

How to get all data in proper format?

Comment: *"I am not getting all in the csv. getting ..."*, What data are you missing?

Comment: In between first header and last header coloum. You can see above example. Data is ... in csv file

Comment: If you try and print a dataframe, Pandas will give you a summary as often it will be huge. That is why you see `...` in the print output.

Comment: Yeah I know but I get ... in csv file also. I don't know why. if possible please run my code once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a Pandas dataframe and print it, Pandas will display a summary of the table based on certain output defaults, i.e. displaying `...` for skipped columns. These defaults though can be altered using various `set_option()` parameters:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1500)
```

Your code appears to be trying to extract all of the tables from that URL and write them all to a single CSV file. The `read_html()` can also take a URL and will automatically return a list of dataframes. This avoids the need to first parse it using `requests` or `beautifulsoup`. So your code could become:

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTQmRGl2aXNpb249MSZVc2VySUQ9MjAyODcmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NSZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNIJkNoYXJhY3RlckQ9MjImRXh0QXBwSUQ9", header=0)

with open('out_table.csv', 'w') as outcsv:   
    for table in tables:
        if not table.empty:    # skip empty dataframes
            table.to_csv(outcsv, mode='a', index=False, sep='|')
```

If further processing is required you would need to first use Pandas calls to reformat each table in `tables` to the required format before writing them all to CSV format. I would recommend identifying each table by its header and then applying suitable formatting. For example you could drop unwanted columns. You might also want to merge some tables.

The reason for identifying each table by its header is that other URLs might not contain the same set of tables.

Comment: Sir, It it possible to get all table in the same format like on the web page?

Comment: I would recommend modifying the Pandas dataframes using Pandas calls before writing to CSV. There are not many options for changing how `read_html()` itself works. Also adding `header=0` will make each dataframe use the first row as the header.